# XSLT Global parameter LCID is empty

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, xslt, data-form-web-part, parameter

According to [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806158%28v=office.14%29.aspx) about XSLT global parameters, in main.xsl there is a parameter named LCID whose value should be

> the value of System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID in string format.

I tried to use it in my DataFormWebPart. I firstly imported the main.xsl file, then tried to output the value of the $LCID parameter, but nothing is shown.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
<xsl:value-of select="$LCID"></xsl:value-of>
```

The value-of $LCID is simply empty.
All the other parameters defined in main.xsl work properly (which is extremely irritating, considering that the one that I need it's the only that doesn't seem to work).

If I use this trick:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Language" Location="Resource(wss,language_value)" />
```

then I can get the user's language in the form `en-us`, but I feel it as a dirty workaround.

So the question is: **why is $LCID empty? How can I get the current user's LCID ?**

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri curly brackets inside the select attribute of a xsl:value-of are illegal (also tried with an asp:label text="{$LCID}" but still nothing is output).

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I see that is file is imported in the OOTB XSLT in the hive. My XSL is in the Style Library. Is that your case as well?

Comment: @GabrielSmoljár I customized the XSLT in SP Designer, so in my case I didn't even have a separate xsl

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with getting the LCID within an event receiver. Finally I addressed it like this `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID` 
or `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name`

It worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: I was looking for a way to get the LCID in the xsl stylesheet without recurring to a C# code solution

Answer (score 0):

Knowing how sensitive xslt is, have you tried:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="$LCID"/>
```

Also look into your xsl:output method.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
    <xsl:param name="Language" />
    <xsl:template match="/" xmlns...>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Language" />
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: Nope. This is the value of the site's LCID, not the current user's LCID, which are two completely different things.